# Is there any difference between very & much?

Tags: adjectives

Please tell which one is correct.
I am much interested. Or I am very Interested. 
Please explain scientifically.

Comment: The answer is very easy: not much difference.

Comment: **very** expresses the degree of something, whereas **much** normally refers to a great quantity of something, although it can be used to express the idea of  "to a great degree", which blurs the boundaries between the two concepts.

Comment: This is very much an interesting question, actually. Thank you very much.

Comment: Something that has not been said and I think is worth mentioning is that, being of verbal origin, "interested" allows the use of "much", and being an adjective, it allows the use of "very". Notice that "I am much interested" comes from "Something interests me much".

Comment: thanks gustavson sir , your reply is quite right. i also search more about this.Then I Find , With past participle, mostly much is used & with present participle mostly very is used except some cases.( such as very tired)

Answer (score 1):

"I am very interested" is correct.

"I am much interested" is in a grey area.  It will sound odd to most people.  Speakers tend to avoid using "much" in affirmative clauses, although it is used in interrogatives, negatives, and when qualified as "very much" (see http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-degree/much-a-lot-lots-a-good-deal-adverbs ).

A small number of expressions sound OK and are idiomatic with affirmative "much".  For example, "I am much obliged".  These expressions just have to be learnt on a case-by-case basis.

By contrast, "I am much disappointed", "I am much happy", "he is much silly" sound extremely awkward and borderline ungrammatical.  "Very disappointed", "very happy", "very silly" would be the accepted forms.

You can say "Do you like the film much?" and "I don't like the film much".  But you can't say "I like the film much".

You can say "I like the film very much", "I like the film so much" and even "I like the film too much", but "much" on its own doesn't work in affirmatives.  In these cases, of course, "very" wouldn't work as a substitute - instead, the substitute would be "a lot": "I like the film a lot".